# Custom function to sum values in row with specific text

Tags: vba, excel

I want to sum a variable sized row with values: From the 5th column to the last filled cell in row 6.

The row in question must contain "`My text`" in column `B`.

So, for example, I want to sum the values below from `E8 to J8`:
[image]

This is the code I'm using:

```
Function cenas()
Application.Volatile

Dim celula
Dim ultAno As Integer
Dim intervalo  As Range
Dim separador As Worksheet

    Set separador = Sheets("Sheet1")
    ultAno = separador.Cells(6, 5).End(xlToRight).Column
    For i = 1 To 50
      celula = separador.Cells(i, 2).Value
      If celula = "My text" Then
        Set intervalo = Sheets(separador).Range(Sheets(separador).Cells(i, 5), Sheets(separador).Cells(i, ultAno))
        cenas = Application.Sum(intervalo)
      End If
    Next i

End Function
```

Which is returning `#VALUE!`

I tried different approaches related with the variables declarations, but can't find a solution.

Comment: Why are you not including D8 in the sum?

Comment: Where is the sum supposed to be written?

Comment: The result is supposed to be written in any cell (out of that table)

Comment: Your function always returns the sum on the last row (50) not of the current row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is with this line

```
Set intervalo = Sheets(separador).Range(Sheets(separador).Cells(i, 5), Sheets(separador).Cells(i, ultAno))
```

There is no need to use the `Sheets()`.  `separador` is set as a sheet.

```
Function cenas()
Application.Volatile

Dim celula
Dim ultAno As Integer
Dim intervalo  As Range
Dim separador As Worksheet

    Set separador = Sheets("Sheet1")
    ultAno = separador.Cells(6, 5).End(xlToRight).Column
    For i = 1 To 50
      celula = separador.Cells(i, 2).value
      If celula = "My text" Then
        Set intervalo = separador.Range(separador.Cells(i, 4), separador.Cells(i, ultAno))
        cenas = Application.sum(intervalo)
      End If
    Next i

End Function
```

If you are going to use a function, why not make it a little more versatile:

```
Function cenas(lkpStr As String)
Application.Volatile

Dim celula
Dim ultAno As Integer
Dim intervalo  As Range
Dim separador As Worksheet

    Set separador = Sheets("Sheet3")
    ultAno = separador.Cells(6, 5).End(xlToRight).Column
    For i = 7 To separador.Cell(7,2).End(xlDown).Row

      If separador.Cells(i, 2).value = lkpStr Then
        Set intervalo = separador.Range(separador.Cells(i, 5), separador.Cells(i, ultAno))
        cenas = Application.sum(intervalo)

      End If
    Next i

End Function

Sub getsum()
Dim t
t = cenas("My Text")
Debug.Print t

End Sub
```

This will allow you to specify the text for which you want to search.  And return the sum of the last one in the group.  You can call this as a UDF in your sheet or by vba code.

Note: if there is more than one "My text" in column B it will only return the last row with "My text" in it.

Comment: I was exactly thinking about that. Passing an argument to the function would help me re-use it in other situations.

Answer (score 1):

Look at something like this.

```
Private Sub CommandButton34_Click()
    Dim ws1 As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lLastCol As Long

    Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    lRow = 1

    ws1.Activate
    'Loop through the rows
    Do While lRow <= ws1.UsedRange.Rows.count

        If ws1.Range("B" & lRow).Value = "My text" Then

            'Get the last col used in that row
            lLastCol = ws1.Cells(lRow, ws1.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column

            'Write the sum to the column after the last used column
            ws1.Cells(lRow, lLastCol + 1).Value = "=sum(D" & lRow & ":" & Col_Letter(lLastCol) & lRow & ")"

        End If
        lRow = lRow + 1
    Loop

End Sub

Function Col_Letter(lngCol As Long) As String
    Dim vArr
    vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")
    Col_Letter = vArr(0)
End Function
```